# Querying DBPedia using SPARQL to find right-wing parties

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to find all the far-right parties in EU, in addition I want their leader.  In dbpedia for property has **is dbpedia-owl:party of** and I dont know how to use it.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT str(?Lparty) as ?Politicalparty str(?Lcountry) as ?EUCountry str(?Lleader) as     ?EUleader
WHERE
{
  ?Party dbpprop:position ?Position ;
         rdfs:label ?Lparty ;
         dbpedia-owl:country ?Country ;
         a dbpedia-owl:PoliticalParty ;

         # The following are the problematic lines

         dbpedia-owl:party ?Leader ;
         rdfs:label ?Lleader.

         # End problematic lines

  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?Lleader), "en")).
  FILTER(?Position IN (dbpedia:Far-right_politics,dbpedia:Nazism, dbpedia:Nationalism)).
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS{?Party dbpprop:dissolved ?otherBalue}).
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS{?Party dbpprop:dissolution ?otherBalue}).
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?Lparty), "en")).
  ?Country dcterms:subject category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union;
           rdfs:label ?Lcountry.
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?Lcountry), "en")).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was solving a query similar to yours and after a while I realised that some of the `?Leaders` are already labels and some others are URIs that the label needs to be extracted. For example, in your condition if you change the "problematic part" into `?Party dbpprop:leader ?Leader.`, you can get answers such as `Hendrik Elias` and `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wies_Moens` at the same time. So if you actually need the label in both cases, you need to decide when to dig deeper. Since my version was part of a bigger program it is faster for me to programatically resolve this issue. Based on these explanations, the easiest query I could write was:

```
SELECT distinct str(?Lparty) as ?Politicalparty str(?Lcountry) as ?EUCountry str(?Leader) as     ?EUleader
WHERE
{
  ?Party dbpprop:position ?Position ;
  rdfs:label ?Lparty ;
  dbpedia-owl:country ?Country ;
  a dbpedia-owl:PoliticalParty.
  ?Party dbpprop:leader ?Leader.

  FILTER(?Position IN (dbpedia:Far-right_politics,dbpedia:Nazism, dbpedia:Nationalism)).
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS{?Party dbpprop:dissolved ?otherBalue}).
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS{?Party dbpprop:dissolution ?otherBalue}).
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?Lparty), "en")).
  ?Country dcterms:subject category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union;
       rdfs:label ?Lcountry.
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?Lcountry), "en")).
```

}